# ORACLE DBA: Ways to check disk_repair_time parameter value

Tags: oracle11g

I am going to make some of my ASM disks offline and before that willing to check the value of "disk_repair_time" parameter.

I have tried executing command (SELECT * FROM v$asm_attribute) on ASM instance but no records were returned.

Also executed (show parameter disk_repair_time;), again no records were returned.

Please help me understand why no records were returned in executing above queries and also help me with the method to check the default value of "disk_repair_time" parameter.

Comment: Try executing `SELECT name AS diskgroup, compatibility AS asm_compat, 
     database_compatibility AS db_compat FROM V$ASM_DISKGROUP;` and check ASM_COMPAT value it must be 11.1 or higher to show in v$asm_attribute

Comment: Thanks @J91321, on executing query suggested by you i found that ASM_COMPAT is 10.1.0.0.0